# Rmarkdown & PDF Output: Evaluate Markdown inside Latex section

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

How can I make it possible that markdown code used inside Latex Code gets evaluated? (Rmarkdown with PDF (Latex) Output)

Very simple minimal example:

```
\begin{center}
**should be bold text**
\end{center}
```

Current output in .tex file after compiling with knitr:

```
\begin{center}
**should be bold text**
\end{center}
```

Expected:

```
\begin{center}
\textbf{should be bold text}
\end{center}
```

I would be happy to find a way to get this working, because I try to find a way in which I can pass a tibble/dataframe through kable/kableExtra. Table cells can already contain Latex code, but no markdown code, since kable converts everything into a Latex structure.

It seems to me like all Markdown code inside any Latex code block doesn't get evaluated.

I know that I can achieve the same result by just using Latex Code, but I prefer using the Markdown shortcuts wherever possible.

**Edit:**

@duckmayr kindly offered to review another minimal example to see how it's possible to automatically change Latex code produced by R functions in order to make it work (together with the proposed & accepted answer, thx). So I'm looking for some kind of wrapper that would work regardless what R function I use (here: one basic R example and a simple kable test; could also be Stargazer, or something)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    df_print: kable
header-includes:
    - \let\Begin\begin
    - \let\End\end
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```


```{r test1, results='asis'}
test = function(x=1){
  cat('\\begin{center}\n**test**\n\\end{center}')
}
test()
```

```{r test2, results='asis'}
kable(data.frame(x=c("**bold text**")),"latex")
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone opened [an issue on the pandoc GitHub repo about this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3145) a couple years ago, and [we can find there a workaround](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3145#issuecomment-302787889): Making LaTeX synonyms for `\begin{}` and `\end{}`. So, to use this in R Markdown, we just put them in `header-includes`:

```
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "5/9/2020"
output:
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: true
header-includes:
    - \let\Begin\begin
    - \let\End\end
---

\Begin{center}

**should be bold text**

\End{center}
```

LaTeX output:

```
... Many initial lines skipped ...
\let\Begin\begin
\let\End\end

\title{Stack Overflow Answer}
\author{duckmayr}
\date{5/9/2020}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}

\textbf{should be bold text}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

PDF output:

[image]

### Update: What about using things like `kable()`?

To deal with using things like `kable()` in R chunks with `results='asis'`, we'll need to fix the output of `kable()`; namely, we'll need to change its `\begin{}` and `\end{}` tags to `\Begin{}` and `\End{}`, and we'll also need to make sure we don't end up converting `\\` sequences to `textbackslash{}`s. Here's how we'd do that:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    df_print: kable
header-includes:
    - \let\Begin\begin
    - \let\End\end
    - \newcommand{\Newrow}{\\}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
allow_markdown <- function(tex) {
    tex <- gsub("begin", "Begin", tex) ## fix \begin{} tags
    tex <- gsub("\\\\end", "\n\\\\End", tex) ## fix \end{} tags
    tex <- gsub("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\Newrow\n", tex) ## fix new row \\
    return(tex)
}
```

```{r test2, results='asis'}
kable(data.frame(x=c("**bold text**")),"latex")
```

```{r test3, results='asis'}
allow_markdown(kable(data.frame(x=c("**bold text**")), "latex"))
```
````

We added a new LaTeX command in the header with `\newcommand{\Newrow}{\\}` so that we can safely add `\\` without them being converted to `\textbackslash{}`. This is necessary because of how we're tricking pandoc into processing the markdown in the environment between `\Begin` and `\End`.

We also added an R function for fixing up the LaTeX output of `kable()` that fixes the begin and end tags and the new row `\\` characters.

Then we get the following LaTeX and PDF output:

```
[header omitted]
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
x\\
\hline
**bold text**\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline

x\\

\hline

\textbf{bold text}\\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @duckmayr, pretty straight forward! Have you any idea what would be the smartest way to replace `\begin` with `\Begin` if the Latex code is actually produced by an R code chunk (with `results="asis"`), i.e. by a function in an R package that I cannot simply rewrite?

Comment: @joffdd You could probably wrap the R function call with `gsub("begin", "Begin", foo(x))`, where `foo(x)` is your actual function call. You'd also have to take care of end/End, so probably `gsub("begin", "Begin", gsub("end", "End", foo(x)))`. Could you [edit] your question to have a reproducible example of that part of your issue? I could easily check and/or adapt my initial thought.

Comment: That's weird that Pandoc is changing `\Begin` and `\End` to their lower-case versions.

Comment: @user2554330 Yeah, that is quite interesting, I didn't think about that

Comment: @joffdd See the update! Glad you added this follow-up question, I think it greatly improves the utility of the answer!

Comment: @duckmayr thx so much! currently in my bigger kable table I still face problems, since there are occurences of `\begingroup` that are replaced too. But I will try to solve that myself and post when I get a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a simple LaTeX environment, I'd recommend that you use fenced `Div` blocks in Pandoc's Markdown ([see this section in the R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html) for more info), e.g.,

````
::: {.center}
**should be bold text**

```{r}
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```
:::
````

In the fenced Div block, you can write arbitrary Markdown content. Besides, this also works for HTML output.

Note that this feature requires a relatively new version of Pandoc, and the development version of **rmarkdown**. You may try the [RStudio Preview version](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) (if you use RStudio), together with `remotes::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')`.